# How split the scene in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

How split and add that elements on the bottom of scene in JavaFX? I would be appreciate for any answer!!!

http://s2.postimg.org/3ouycznvd/image.png

Comment: Have you read through the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102)?

Comment: After you have finished the layout tutorial recommended by James and written some programs using the information in it to ensure you understand the basic concepts, download [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) and run through a [SceneBuilder layout tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part1/).  Once you have done that, you should be able to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own question.